# Finding a value to prove a probability mass function.

Tags: probability, functions

Ive been given the probability mass function:

Pr(X = x) = A(6.75x - x^2)         (equation 1)

with x ∈ {1,2,3,4,5}

and I need to go about finding the value for A so that the probability mass function for X(equation 1) is valid.

Then I need to find the mean and variance of X using the probability mass function (equation 1).

How do i go about completing these two questions. Any help would be great.

Comment: First thing you need is the **support** for this PMF.

Comment: Next thing you need is to list *what* are the requirements of a valid PMF.

Comment: Then you'll need the definitions for expectation and variance of a discrete random variable.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance